# How to unbind all events inside a particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent div , say with id="to-remove"

This div has multiple children divs and each children div also can have in-turn multiple divs and each of them can have href and/or onclick events.

Is there way to remove all these events from inside this parent div using jquery..?

Comment: Please take some time to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). If someone's answer has answered your question, please don't forget to click on the check mark next to their [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/171243).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Did you try [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/):

```
$('#to-remove *').unbind('click'); // just for click events
$('#to-remove *').unbind(); // for all events
```

And as of jQuery 1.7, the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements. (from `.unbind()` documentation) So if you're using jQuery > 1.7.x then this would be better:

```
$('#to-remove *').off();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, only unbind was not removing all events. So i used these three: .unbind('click') , .attr('onClick','') , attr('href','');

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('#to-remove *').unbind();
//or you could assign some class and do
$('.some-class').unbind();
```